# Qual a diferença entre codec, formato de arquivo e extensão?

Tags: arquivo, extensão

Já vi falar que mp3, mp4 e etc... usa o mesmo codec, mas o que são cada uma e qual a diferença?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos pegar um exemplo: "imagem.jpg"

- **Formato do arquivo**: é a forma como os dados são armazenados no arquivo. Nesse caso é uma imagem, que foi "compactada" [com o compressão JPG/JPEG](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG). Em muitos tipos de arquivo além do conteúdo em si isso implica em ter um cabeçalho (*header*) no começo do arquivo contendo informações sobre esse conteúdo (metadados) como identificador do formato de arquivo, dimensões (no caso de imagens), autor, local, *encoding* utilizado, etc.
- **Codec**: *(de "**cod**ificador-**dec**odificador")* é o *software* que foi utilizado para, a partir de um arquivo no formato "padrão" ou mais simples, gerar um **arquivo no formato** esperado. Ou seja, é o codec que gerar o gera o arquivo no formato certo. Outros exemplos seriam `mpg` e `mkv` para vídeo, ou seja, exitem *codecs* que processam um vídeo e geram videos compactados nesses outros formatos.
- **Extensão**: nada é mais é que a parte do nome do arquivo que identifica o formato ou o tipo do arquivo. No exemplo, o ".jpg" é extensão que indica que é um arquivo com o formato JPG/JPEG. Uma observação é que, a extensão é usada pelos programas que vão abrir esse arquivo para "saber" que foi codificado (*encoding*) naquele formato, mas isso não significa que necessariamente aquele arquivo está nesse formato. As extensões ajudam o SO a associar determinado programa a um tipo de formato de arquivo, assim por exemplo ao clicar num arquivo o SO sabe qual software deve usar para "abrir" ou "ler" aquele arquivo. Existiu uma restrição histórica para a extensão ter no máximo três letras, mas hoje isso não é mais verdade, embora possa ser visto em algumas extensões tradicionais como `.exe`, `.zip`, `.txt`, `.jpg`, `.gif`, etc.

Como bônus temos também o termo **formato de compressão**, que tem a ver com comprimir dados (*codec*) em um formato mais portável (compactado) e/ou mais otimizado para transmissão. Essa compressão pode ser *lossy* (sofre perda de informação em relação ao original) ou *lossless* (não há perda). Por exemplo, MPEG é uma família de formatos *lossy* voltado para *streaming* de áudio/vídeo que inclui o MPEG-1 Layer 3, que é o famoso `MP3`. PKZIP e RAR são formatos conhecidos de compressão *lossless* de arquivos em geral (arquivos `.zip` e `.rar`, respectivamente). Note que certos arquivos compensa compactar, para fins de transporte/armazenamento, outros já são orginalmente bem compactados por algum outro formato e há pouca ou nenhuma vantagem em compactar em outro, podendo deixar o arquivo inclusive maior do que já era.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso respondeu totalmente minha pergunta

Comment: @Gustavosoares Ótimo. Lembra do [tour]? Pode aceitar a resposta então :)

Comment: Ok então vou lá

Comment: @Gustavosoares É pequeno gafanhoto, eu vi o +1 mas faltou "aceitar" mesmo, que é marcar verdinho abaixo desse número à esquerda da resposta. Veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/495152/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-codec-formato-de-arquivo-e-extens%c3%a3o#comment919644_495152)

Comment: @Piovezan, o +1 que viu é meu e o outro é seu.

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/736x/d5/54/5d/d5545d8fb22c51574148c2fa709ec1d3--betrayal-so-sad.jpg

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk....:D

Comment: muito boa essa imagem @Piovezan :D